# Expand Ubuntu drive on VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, partitioning, virtual-machine

I will preface my question by saying I don't have a lot of experience with VirtualBox or Ubuntu, but did my best to read the information relevant to my problem and can't figure out why the solutions out there won't work for me.

I have guest Ubuntu running on virtualbox 6.1 through host Windows 10. Originally there was a 500 GB VDI created for the guest, but I wanted to expand that to 800 GB.

In order to do so, I went to “File > Virtual Media Manager” in the VirtualBox UI and expanded the drive from 500 to 800 GB. Then I logged into the guest and installed/ran gparted to allocate the new space to my main partition. These steps all appeared to be successful.

VirtualBox reports an actual size of 500 GB and a virtual size of 800 GB. Gparted reports 800 GB size in the lvm2 pv filesystem with 500 GB used and 300 GB unused.

What step am I missing?

Comment: Silly question, but did you even restart the VM with Ubuntu on it?

Comment: You need to look into running `pvresize` and `lvresize`. First command make lvm aware of the increased disk space. Second command resizes the individual logical volumes. Use the `-r` option to resize the file system along with the volume

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I have restarted several times.

@doneal24 I ran `sudo pvresize /dev/sda2` and the output indicates 1 physical volume was resized. I'm not sure what exactly I should input for arguments using the `lvresize` command, could you be more specific?

Comment: @doneal24 You should post your comment as a full answer to get credit for your work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure I use after the virtual disk is resized. Does not require a reboot.

In vSphere client, browse to the VM, edit settings, increase the size of the hard disk

```
echo 1 > /sys/class/scsi_device/2:0:0:0/device/rescan
fdisk -l /dev/sda to confirm the new size

fdisk /dev/sda
```

Delete the last partition.

Recreate the last partition with default answers:

```
partprobe

pvresize /dev/sda1
```

`vgdisplay` to confirm.

`lvresize` or `lvcreate` as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was found thanks to @doneal24.

First I ran `sudo pvresize /dev/sda2` though I'm not entirely sure if this step was required for the next command I ran, which was `sudo lvresize --size 800G /dev/ubuntu-vg/root` followed by `sudo resize2efs /dev/ubuntu-vg/root`.

Comment: Well, you should [encourage doneal24 to post their comment as an answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1709407/expand-ubuntu-drive-on-virtualbox?noredirect=1#comment2634809_1709407). On this site, many times people post comments as suggestions and if they end up being answers, they post it as such to earn rep.